# Do entangled particles really exchange information?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-entanglement

Is it possible that entangled particles don't exchange information at all, e.g. maybe something happened at the moment they were split that made them opposite?

Comment: Can you give a reference stating that they exchange information? (That isn't a pop-sci / layman's description of entanglement)

Comment: i thought that the faster than light communication was just something that everybody agreed upon, turns out i'm wrong.

Answer (score 1):

They do not exchange information. When Alice measures her particle, she obtains information about Bob's particle, but that information comes from knowledge of the state in which the particles were created, not from Bob's particle. Neither Bob (nor his particle) obtain any information from Alice's measurement, until later, when the results of their measurements are brought together.